# Deleting element from array and moving remaining element using nested loops?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested

This is my code so far:

```
public class CustomerListerArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //creating the array 
    String[] customerName = new String [7]; 
    customerName[0] = "Beth"; 
    customerName[1] = "Jerry";
    customerName[2] = "Rick"; 
    customerName[3] = "Summer";
    customerName[4] = "Morty";

    // first loop/test
    for(String x : customerName) { 
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    //second loop/test
    customerName[5] = customerName[3];
    customerName[6] = customerName[4];
    customerName[3] = "Rick";
    customerName[4] = "Jessica";

    for(String x : customerName) { 
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");

    //third loop/test

    int i = 0; 
    int p = 0;

    for(String x : customerName) { 
        for(i = 0; i < customerName.length - 1; ++i) { 
            if((customerName[i] == "Rick")){
                for (p = i; p < customerName.length; ++p){
                customerName[i] = customerName[i +1];
                }
            }
            }

            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }


}
```

In the third loop test, I am trying to take the "Rick"s from the array, delete them and move the remaining elements up. The output should be this:

"Beth
Jerry
Jessica
Summer
Morty"

Right now, the program outputs this:

"Beth
Jerry
Rick
Summer
Morty
null
null

Beth
Jerry
Rick
Rick
Jessica
Summer
Morty

Beth
Jerry
Jessica
Jessica
Jessica
Summer
Morty"

I don't understand why three "Jessica"s are printing at the end. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: @shmosel I tried but was confused about breakpoints. I am using Eclipse.

Comment: The innermost statement within your loops `customerName[i] = customerName[i+1];` looks wrong to me. I think you meant to use `p`, not `i`, in the array indices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
private static void output() {

    String[] str_array = {"Beth", "Jerry", "Rick", "Summer", "Morty"};
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
    list.remove("Rick");
    str_array = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (String x : str_array) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Please remember to import the appropriate API's above your class declaration.

`import java.util.ArrayList;`

`import java.util.Arrays;`

`import java.util.List;`

Comment: Please explain what this does differently, and what was originally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST OF ALL -- doing `customerName[i] == "Rick"` is a classic newbie mistake; whatever it looks like, it does NOT tell you whether that value is "Rick" (unless you've done some special things we won't go into). It will tell you whether the object at `customerName[i]` is the same object as your literal "Rick", which isn't likely in a production environment. You need the `equals()` method of the String class; look it up and remember this. For example, `if (customerName[i].equals("Rick"))`.

Read this for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

As for Jessica, if you move that value from `[i]` to `[j]`, then she is still in `[i]`; if you want to "remove" jessica, you should set the value at `[i]` to something else.

Comment: For the record, `==` probably will work in this example, because the values are hardcoded.

Comment: Why would [i] still be jessica? I thought [i] would be redefined with each repetition of the loop

Comment: @Ryan If [i] is still Jessica, then do ` customerName[i] = ""; customerName[i] = customerName[i +1];`. That should work, that code empties index [i], and then immediately fills it with the next element. (Note: I haven't tested it).

Comment: @fs2ly I tried it and it didn't work, how is it different than what I had before?